# C# multiple switch case combinations in string

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, switch-statement

I recently ran into a rather interesting issue while converting a classic ASP application to C# .NET. In this MVC application, the front end checkboxes (below) are read in as a string, which can be in multiple combinations. A C# case statement determines the correct combination and concatenates the SQL statement in the case statement to a SELECT in the data layer file.

```
<input value="A" type="checkbox" class="material-checkbox" 
id="" name="checkbox" checked />
<input value="B" type="checkbox" class="material-checkbox" 
id="" name="checkbox" />
<input value="C" type="checkbox" class="material-checkbox" 
id="" name="checkbox" />
<input value="D" type="checkbox" class="material-checkbox" 
id="" name="checkbox" />
```

Comment: can you please share some more about your four checkbox and there values as well as some sample data fro switch case.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not following at all.  You are going to need to flesh out this question and provide information in a what that someone who is looking at this from the outside might understand what you are talking about.  For example, what does _"the C# dictates what statements will be added to a SELECT"_ mean.  What does the `SQL;` do/mean?  Why would you ever want to have more than one `case "A":` clause in a switch statement (the second one would never execute)?

Comment: How can your second `case "A":` throw an error - it doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

there are multiple ways to do this: combination of ABCD can create total 15 combinations. I have created all 15 combination in the switch cases:

```
string checkboxvalue = "";
if(chkA.Checked()) checkboxvalue +="A";
if(chkB.Checked()) checkboxvalue +="B";
if(chkC.Checked()) checkboxvalue +="C";
if(chkD.Checked()) checkboxvalue +="D";



switch(checkboxvalue)
    {
        case "ABCD":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "ABC":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "ABD":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "ACD":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "BCD":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "AB":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "AC":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "AD":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "BC":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "BD":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "CD":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "A":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "B":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "C":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case "D":
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

***Assuming the user selected boxes A,C,D.***

```
strSql += "SELECT column1, column2, ...
      FROM table_name;"


     switch(checkboxvalue)
        {
        case (("ABCD")): //<---Contains "ACD" but not "B" NO MATCH
        strSql += "AND .....;"
        break;

        case (("ABC")): //<---- Contains "A" but not "BC" NO MATCH
        strSql += "AND.......;"
        break;

        case (("AB")): //<--Contains "A" but no "B" NO MATCH
        strSql += "AND......;"
        break; 

        case (("AC")): //<--Contains "AC" but no "D" NO MATCH
        strSql += "AND.....";
        break;

        case (("ACD")): //<--MATCH! 
        strSql += "AND......"; //<--add to select to pull correct data 
        break;

        }
```

Comment: I'm not following.  Where does "ACD" come from.  What does `SQL;` do/mean?  And, if you are going to post code, can you make it be compilable (i.e., put a `//` before your `<--Contains` comments).  What is with the weird double-parens around the `case` strings.  Are they significant (I realize the `switch` statement's capability has changed recently, but how does `(("ABCD"))` differ from plain old `"ABCD"`

Comment: The double parens are simply for readability. You can simply put "ABCD" omitting them completely. The SQL; denotes a sql statement within the case statement as I prefaced in my original question portion. Converting classic ASP to ASP. NET is not easy for those of us who are new to it, and this seems like it could be a fairly common problem. Just doing my personal best to help some other programmer perhaps. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are probably trying to build where clause conditions based on checkbox options being checked. Here, if we try to use a switch statement, we would probably end up writing a lot of cases for each combinations, which wouldn't be efficient (Something like - a, ab, abc, abcd, ac, acd, ad, b, bc, bcd, bd, c, cd, d). If the values don't come in order that combination will multiply. Even worse. So, It will be beneficial to use if simple conditional statements with a string builder to hold final string something like below -

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
if (checkbox1.checked)
{
    sb.Apppend("Condition1");
}

if (checkbox2.checked)
{
    sb.Apppend("Condition2");
}

if (checkbox3.checked)
{
    sb.Apppend("Condition3");
}

if (checkbox4.checked)
{
    sb.Apppend("Condition4");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're basically comparing boolean values, I would suggest making a table to map the different checkbox combinations you'd have, in order to validate if you'd be better with if-elses or few nested if's instead of switches. Try recosiderating how many outputs you'll have and which actions you'd need to perform in such cases.

```
static void executeSQL(string checkboxes)
{
    switches checkbox_switches = new switches(checkboxes.Contains('A'), checkboxes.Contains('B'), checkboxes.Contains('C'), checkboxes.Contains('D'));
    if (checkbox_switches.action_A)
    {
        //Execute SQL
    }
    else if (checkbox_switches.action_B)
    {
        //Execute SQL
    }
    else if (checkbox_switches.action_C)
    {
        //Execute SQL
    }
    else if (checkbox_switches.action_D)
    {
        //Execute SQL
    }
    else if (checkbox_switches.action_E)
    {
        //Execute SQL
    }
}

struct switches
{
    public bool action_A, action_B, action_C, action_D, action_E;

    public switches(bool A, bool B, bool C, bool D)
    {
        action_A = A && B;
        action_B = B || D;
        action_C = C && D;
        action_D = action_A && C;
        action_E = !A && !B && !C && D;
    }
}
```